# Disable use of a second monitor while keeping it enabled

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a dual monitor setup, but not in the traditional sense - I have a htpc connected to my TV via the HDMI port and also to my AVR via DP. The TV is HDMI 2.0 and the AVR is HDMI 1.4, so I have it set up this way to get 4k60 video on the TV while still being able to use the AVR for audio at the same time.

So, I have two desktops, with only one being used and I would like to prevent use of the AVR desktop as it is only used for audio. I cant disable the AVR 'monitor' because it also disables sound output to that HDMI sink. I have shrunk it down to its minimum resolution, but the mouse can move onto it and programs sometimes open on it, which means I have to switch inputs on the TV to move it to the main screen. Mirroring the two displays doesnt work due to the different resolutions in play.

I'm running X11 Xubuntu 19.10 with an Intel GPU.

So anyone know of any way to disable the use of a second monitor while keeping it enabled?

Comment: How did you disable the AVR? What else did you try already?

Comment: Hi, I tried disabling it via 'xrandr -off' which also disabled audio. I have solved the issue via a suggestion on reddit and Ill add an answer to this question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to disable use of the second screen thanks to a suggestion by user grumbel
 on reddit. They suggested "You can solve the mouse issue by making a xrandr configuration that has the unused monitor overlap with the one that you use. You can use arandr to do that with a bit drag&drop."

So I have added the argument "--pos 544x280" to my xrandr command which disables use of the second monitor and doesnt impact the use of the primary monitor. After running that command I can no longer move the mouse or drag windows onto that monitor.

For completeness, the entire command I use is:

```
xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode "1920x1080" --refresh "60.00" --primary --output HDMI1 --mode "720x400" --refresh "70.08" --pos 544x280
```